# MYSQL unselect query from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, unselect

Hi I have this two table

table 1

```
id    Selection  
-------------------
1     John           
2     Ely               
3     Marcus            
4     Steve           
5     Fritz           
6     Orly           
7     Carlo              
8     Lee
```

table 2

```
id    Selected 
-------------------
1     John                         
3     Marcus 
4     Steve                     
5     Fritz           
7     Carlo
```

the return would be the unselected rows. What would be the query for this output

```
id    Selection 
-------------------         
2     Ely                         
6     Orly                  
8     Lee
```

Comment: This pattern is referred to as an "anti-join". Usually the most efficient way to get this result is a LEFT JOIN operation, and then eliminate any rows that matched. What you are left with is the unmatched rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to join both table and `t2.ID IS NULL` to remove common records

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
 WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Output:

```
╔════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ SELECTION ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  2 ║ Ely       ║
║  6 ║ Orly      ║
║  8 ║ Lee       ║
╚════╩═══════════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38fd4/1)

Comment: +1. This is the familiar anti-join pattern. Very nice.  @Markie Mark: And beyond hoping it would work, you might try to understand how it works, and be able to confirm that it does work.

Comment: it works.. my bad I switch the table joins.. thanks for this very bery helpful

Comment: @MarkieMark - Glad! For more details related to how joins works see: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Left Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

```
 Select t1.id,t2.selection from 
 table1 t1 left join table2 t2 
 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
 where t2.id is null;
```

Comment: You just changed the whole answer and now it's exact answer as mine! :P

Comment: @hims056 because I realized that this is MySQL and not Oracle.

Comment: really weird.. I exactly doing your answers with my database.. but I cant get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Use This Query. Its worked for you.

```
select table1.* from table1 where table1.id not in (select id from table2)
```

Comment: I remember using this on small database.. it works, but if you have bigger table this query gives you slow result and unwanted results.